# How to find out from which pom.xml a dependency is coming

Tags: maven, pom.xml

With complex builds, it can be hard to find out in which `pom.xml` a dependency is actually specified.

Is there a plugin or a parameter that helps to find the `pom.xml` that is specifying a dependency? Ideally, it would help normal dependencies as well as with plugin dependencies.

All the searches only point to the dependency plugins and ways to find which jar actually gets picked. The other alternative would be to just grep all the poms which can be difficult when they are not in a single directory tree.

`dependency:tree` does not work (I think). If `A` specifies `B` as the parent, and `B` specifies a dependency to `C`, in `dependency:tree` the dependency will seem to come from `A`, but I want to find `B`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I updated the question to clarify why.

Comment: @JensSchauder You're going to have to provide more details on what you're doing because I use this technique frequently to track down rogue dependencies in large multi-module projects. BTW, declaring dependencies (not dependencyManagement) in parent poms is about as evil as global variables